# Sikuli recognizes images on the main screen only

Tags: java, sikuli

I'm working on a Sikuli project and using a multi-screen platform to do so. Right now Sikuli does not recognize images on my secondary screen.

I've been given a Sikuli executer class that I can use in my work but cannot change. The class, amongst other things, defines a Screen instance to recognize images on, like so:

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
```

Sikuli documentation says that this way the object representing the primary monitor is created.

Question: How do I make Sikuli recognize images on both screens if I cannot modify the executer class?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean when you say "executer class" but generally, if for some reason you can't just define another `Screen` object that points to a non-primary monitor (e.g. `Screen sc2 = new Screen(1)`), you can define a object of class `ScreenUnion()` like this:

```
Screen union = Screen.all();
```

This will result in a single screen area that covers all detected monitors and will start at 0,0 on the primary screen.